# SQL Server Import and Export Wizard Error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ms-jet-ace

I'm trying to import an 82k+ row table from an access db to SQL Server 2008.

Using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, I get an error at about 78k records entered.

Here's the error:

```
Error 0xc0208265: Data Flow Task 1:
Failed to retrieve long data for column "members_notes".

Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task 1: 
There was an error with output column "members_notes" (41) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (11).
The column status returned was: "DBSTATUS_UNAVAILABLE".

Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: 
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.
The "output column "members_notes" (41)" failed because error code 0xC0209071 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "members_notes" (41)" specifies failure on error.

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1:
SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.
The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - Query" (1) returned error code 0xC0209029. 
The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput().
The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

The members_notes column in the access database is a memo field.  In the SQL Server table to which this data is being transfered, I've defined the field as nvarchar(MAX).

I have searched for this error message and found articles suggesting to shrink my SQL db and clear my temp files on the computer doing the Export/Import, none of which worked.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Can you fix the blockquote so it is in code and not so jumbled?

Comment: As you already indicated, you cleaned your temp files. There is a [bug report][1] but is has been fixed in SQL Server Integration Services 2008. [1]: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=346675

Comment: Have you tried bisecting your problem i.e. splitting data into packages of 1000 records (or smaller) or even tried to import one row only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started searching the memo field in the Access database.  The last row contained '#Error' in the memo field.  When I clicked in that field I got the following message:

> "The Microsoft Jet database engine
>   stopped the process because you and
>   another user are attempting to change
>   the same data at the same time"

I ran Compact and Repair on the Access database.  That placed a bunch of # characters in the memo field for that specific record.

I then attempted the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard again.  It worked perfectly that time!

Comment: You had a corrupted memo pointer. The compact cleans that enough that apparently the import can work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to up your answer dpii but it definitely worked for me. This problem was doing my head in and a simple compact and repair made it go away. Also beware other usesr using the file concurrently wyhile you are uploading (or having the file open yourself in Access) or you may encounter this error

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a bug in SQL Server 2005 that supposed to be fixed, see [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=346675)

Edit: Per your comment below, it is fixed in [2008 SP1 CU5](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975977).

Comment: I am running SQL Server 2008 SP1, so I'm not sure if this bug has persisted through from 2005.

I am installing 2008 SP1 CU5 to see if it resolves the issue and will report back.

Thanks...

Comment: After installing 2008 SP1 CU5 on both the SQL server I'm copying the data to and the dev box I'm running the update from, I get the same error message.

I've seen articles that say that the message that I'm seeing presents itself for a number of issues.  It makes me think that it is possible that it isn't related to the 2005 issue.

I wonder if there is a way to get more information about this specific situation?